# NameError instance of WindowManager is not defined kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm getting a `NameError` saying the instance of my `WindowManager` isn't defined but I am defining it in the `build` class `sm = WindowManager()`. This used to work but now throws this error and I can't see what's been changed.

When the user logs in it should transfer them to the information page but instead the app is crashing.

Error

```
   File "C:/Users/callu/PycharmProjects/FirstApp/main.py", line 54, in login
     sm.current = "information"
 NameError: name 'sm' is not defined
```

py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
import mysql.connector
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton, MDRoundFlatIconButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database=""
         )

cur = mydb.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS meet")

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (email VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255))")

cur.close()
mydb.close()


class LoginWindow(Screen):
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def login(self, email):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="")
        cur = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %s and password = %s", (email, self.password.text))
        result = cur.fetchone()
        mydb.commit()
        cur.close()
        mydb.close()
        if result:
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "information"
        else:
            invalid_login()

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"),
                   Information(name="information")]
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)

        sm.current = "login"
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kv file

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    CreateAccountWindow:
    Information:
    Finder:
    ChatPage:


<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    email: email
    password: password

    FloatLayout:

        FloatLayout:

            Image:
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.01, "y": 0.3}
                source: 'contactless payment.png'

            MDTextField:
                write_tab: False
                hint_text: "Enter your email"
                id: email
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.75, 0.15
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "top": 0.575}

            MDTextField:
                write_tab: False
                hint_text: "Enter your password"
                password: True
                id: password
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.75, 0.15
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "top": 0.4}

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                back_color: 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1
                text: "Login"
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.2}
                on_release: root.login(email.text)

            Button:
                text: "Don't have an account?"
                font_size: 20
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                underline: True
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.05
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.07}
                on_release: app.root.current = "create account"

<Information>:
    name: "information"

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "My Conversations"
                on_release: app.root.current = "login"
                icon: "chat-outline"
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "Logout"
                on_release: app.root.current = "login"
                icon: "account"

        FloatLayout:
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                md_bg_color: 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: root.ids.nav_layout.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

            Label:
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                text: "When are you going to the supermarket?"
                underline: True
                font_size: 20
                multiline: True
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "y": 0.7}
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint: 0.75, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: "center"

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Select date"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.35, "top": 0.65}
                on_release: root.select_date()

            Label:
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                text: "Which supermarket are you going to?"
                underline: True
                font_size: 20
                multiline: True
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "y": 0.4}
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint: 0.75, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: "center"

            Chooser:
                id: location
                write_tab: False
                hint_text: "Enter the address"
                choiceslist: ['Sainsburys Fulham Wharf 27 Townmead Rd London SW6 2GD', 'SW18 4LA', 'RH3 7JS']
                font_size: 25
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.75, 0.15
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "top": 0.325}

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                md_bg_color: 0, 0.6, 0, 1
                text: "Confirm"
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.075
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.125}
                on_release: root.update_date()
                on_release: root.update_location()
                on_release: root.search_database()
                on_release: app.root.current = "finder"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to keep a reference to your `ScreenManager` in the `MyApp` class with
`self.sm = WindowManager()`, and use the `self.sm` instead of the `sm`.

You can then access it from the `py` using `App.get_running_app().sm`, and from the `kv` using `app.sm`